# Problema de guardado de datos en php

Tags: php, html

### MI CODIGO PHP

```
<?php  
    
    $dni= $_POST["DNI"];
    $nombre=$_POST["NOMBRE"];
    $apellidos=$_POST["APELLIDOS"];
    $direccion=$_POST["DIRECCION"];
    $telefono=$_POST["telefono"];
    $socio=$_POST["socio"];
    $fecha_nacimiento=$_POST["fecha_nacimiento"];
    
    
    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_usuario="root";
    $db_contra=NULL ;
    $db_nombre="biblioteca";
    
    
    
    
    
    $connexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    
    if( mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
    
          echo "Hubo un problema con la base de datos error al conectar";
    
          exit() ;
      }
    
   mysqli_select_db($connexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la Base de datos");
    
   mysqli_set_charset($connexion,"utf8");
    
    
  $instruccion_SQL = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('$dni','$nombre','$apellidos','$direccion','$telefono','$socio','$fecha_nacimiento')";
    
   $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion,$instruccion_SQL);
    
   if($resultado == FALSE){
     echo "error en la consulta";
   } else {
     echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
     echo "<table><tr><td>dni:$dni</td></tr>";
     echo "<tr><td>nombre:$nombre</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>apellidos:$apellidos</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>direccion:$direccion</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>telefono:$telefono</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>socio:$socio</td></tr>" ;
     echo "<tr><td>fecha_nacimiento:$fecha_nacimiento</td> </tr></table>" ;    
    }        
    mysqli_close($connexion);    
?>
```

### MI CODIGO HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Biblioteca</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <header>
            <h1>Usuario</h1>
        </header>
    
        <form action="tablausuario.php" method="post"><br>
    
            DNI:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="DNI"><br>
            NOMBRE:<br>
            <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="NOMBRE"><br>
            APELLIDOS:<br>
            <input type="text" name="APELLIDOS" value="" placeholder="APELLIDOS"><br>
            DIRECCION:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DIRECCION" value="" placeholder="DIRECCION"><br>
            TELEFONO:<br>
            <input type="text" name="TELEFONO" value="" placeholder="TELEFONO"><br>
            SOCIO:<br>
            <input type="text" name="SOCIO" value="" placeholder="SI/NO"><br>
            FECHA_NACIMIENTO:<br>
            <input type="text" name="FECHA_NACIMIENTO" value="" placeholder="AAAA-MM-DD"><br>
    
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    
    
        </form>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Mi duda es debido a que estoy haciendo una base de datos con Xampp con php, el problema reside en que los datos teléfono, socio y nacimiento, no me los guarda en la base de datos, el DNI, nombre, apellidos y dirección me los guarda sin problema, el error que me da es Undefined Index en los 3, he probado cambiando las mayusculas y minusculas, he mirado si me ha faltado algun punto y coma, si esta mal escrito y aun asi, no logro localizarlo
En la base de datos de xampp estan puestos como

```
telefono varchar 9
socio boolean
fecha_nacimiento date
```

Alguna ayuda a ser posible? gracias

Comment: en la consulta de insercion esos campos estan como literales, no como variables. TE falta el $ delante de cada una.

Comment: @Jakala no ha funcionado, sigue igual, pero en la base de datos de xampp ya no me salen los nombres de las tablas y ya, gracias

Comment: @Maldo_96 Debes respetar las mayúsculas y minúsculas de los **name=** tambien en los $_POST... si en los name pones TELEFONO en el $_POST también debe ser en mayúsculas, y si te fijas lo haces mal en esos 3 que dices que no funcionan.

Comment: cierto, debes respetar la sintaxis del name que agregas por eso no encuentra esas variables, masterguru tiene razon.

Comment: @masterguru funciona, muchas gracias por la ayuda y tambien a los demas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi solución y para mejorar el procesamiento de datos es hacerlo mediante JS, evitando usar el `form action=""`

Por que a mi me habia pasado que luego cuando capturaba mis datos algunos o no los capturaba bien en el caso de las fechas o simplemente no lo detectaba

Entonces preferi usar un formulario que mandara los datos por POST con Jquery

De la siguiente manera:

mira te mando el ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Biblioteca</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <header>
            <h1>Usuario</h1>
        </header>
    
        <form method="post"><br>
    
            DNI:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DNI" value="" placeholder="DNI"><br>
            NOMBRE:<br>
            <input type="text" name="NOMBRE" value="" placeholder="NOMBRE"><br>
            APELLIDOS:<br>
            <input type="text" name="APELLIDOS" value="" placeholder="APELLIDOS"><br>
            DIRECCION:<br>
            <input type="text" name="DIRECCION" value="" placeholder="DIRECCION"><br>
            TELEFONO:<br>
            <input type="text" name="TELEFONO" value="" placeholder="TELEFONO"><br>
            SOCIO:<br>
            <input type="text" name="SOCIO" value="" placeholder="SI/NO"><br>
            FECHA_NACIMIENTO:<br>
            <input type="text" name="FECHA_NACIMIENTO" value="" placeholder="AAAA-MM-DD"><br>
    
            <input type="button" value="submit" id='manda_info'>
    
    
        </form>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.js" ></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#manda_info').on('click',function(){
                var dni = $('#DNI').val();
                var nombre = $('#NOMBRE').val();
                var apellidos = $('#APELLIDOS').val();
                var direccion = $('#DIRECCION').val();
                var tel = $('#TELEFONO').val();
                var socio = $('#SOCIO').val();
                var fec_nacimiento = $('#FECHA_NACIMIENTO').val();
                var datos = {
                    dni:dni,
                    nombre:nombre,
                    apellidos:apellidos,
                    direccion:direccion,
                    tel:tel,
                    socio:socio,
                    fec_nacimiento:fec_nacimiento
                }
                var json = JSON.stringify(datos);
                $.post("php/tu_php.php",{data:json},function(){

                }).done(function(resp){
                    alert(resp);
                    location.reload();
                })

            })
        })
    </script>
    
    </body>






    </html>
```

Este seria tu PHP:

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
            $datos = json_encode($_POST["data"]);
            
            $DNI = $datos["dni"];
            $nombre=$datos["nombre"];
            $apellidos=$datos["apellidos"];
            $direccion=$datos["direccion"];
            $telefono=$datos["tel"];
            $socio=$datos["socio"];
            $fecha_nacimiento=$datos["fec_nacimiento"];
            
            
            $db_host="localhost";
            $db_usuario="root";
            $db_contra=NULL ;
            $db_nombre="biblioteca";
            
            
            
            $connexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
            
            if( mysqli_connect_errno())
              {
            
                  echo "Hubo un problema con la base de datos error al conectar";
            
                  exit() ;
              }
            
           mysqli_select_db($connexion,$db_nombre) or die ("No se encuentra la Base de datos");
            
           mysqli_set_charset($connexion,"utf8");
            
            
              $instruccion_SQL = "INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('$dni','$nombre','$apellidos','$direccion','$telefono','$socio','$fecha_nacimiento')";
                
               $resultado = mysqli_query($connexion,$instruccion_SQL);
                
        if($resultado == FALSE){
             echo "error en la consulta";
           } else {
              return "Registro exitoso";
mysqli_close($connexion);   
            } 
    
    
    ?>
```

Comment: en el telefono hay algun fallo, pero le echare un ojo, de todos modos lo guardo para emergencia por si llega la fecha limite, porque mi profesor lo quiere con php y html solamente, no quiere otro lenguaje, muchas gracias por la ayuda